# Object.create(Function.prototype) sets direct properties apart from being these present as part of the prototype object?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Why are the properties `arguments` and `caller` set as static properties when creating `a` object?. they're are present in both places.

[image]

I came across with this issue when trying to find out how the `Function` object implicitly inherits on creating classes/functions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that `arguments` becomes an actual variable that can be accessed inside the function without first accessing any parent properties, unlike name, length, etc, not sure about `caller` though. As for why all of the other properties like bind apply etc didn't get copied they're functions which may not be stringified

Comment: @bluejayke As far as understand all properties in `Function.prototype` should go to the `a.__proto__ ` and that's that.

Comment: but most of the properties are functions anyway, only name and length were left out